# Импорт csv файла в mariadb через python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mariadb

Хочу сделать импорт данных из csv в таблицу, через python(mysql-connector-python).

Из консоли mysql под root даёт загрузить. Из по пользователя inventory не даёт, тут понятно что надо наверное дать права(FILE), как это сделать пока не разобрался.

Python скрипт выполняю на машине, где установлена СУБД(mariabd), в подключении коннектора прописан root, тем не менее при попытке загрузить csv файл мне пишет: `"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"`.

1. Как сделать, чтоб через python скрипт давало загрузить csv файл с localhost и удаленно с другой машины?
2. Как дать соответствующие права, для этой же операции, но только для пользователя inventory?

```py
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="132",
    database="inventory")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/country.csv' INTO TABLE ook FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"';"
mycursor.execute(sql)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *надо наверное дать права(FILE), как это сделать пока не разобрался.* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'inventory'@'%';` - выполнять из-под рута. И надо проверить значение `SELECT @@secure_file_priv;` - для использования произвольного каталога там должна быть пустая строка (не NULL).

Comment: @Akina там NULL

Comment: NULL полностью блокирует общение с файловой системой. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv Измените значение в файле конфигурации и перезапустите сервер.

Comment: @Akina  Ок, спасибо. Может еще подскажите, если через консуль делать импорт то команда (LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/country.csv' INTO TABLE ook FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"';) работает, но если я пытаюсь выполнить её через коннектор на python то ругается на синтаксис (код коннектора приведём выше.)

Comment: Я с питоном на "ой, что это?". Но могу предположить, что mycursor.execute предназначен для выполнения запросов, которые возвращают набор записей, тогда как LOAD DATA никаких записей не возвращает. Так что поищите, какой метод надо использовать для DML (всяких INSERT/DELETE и т.п.).

Comment: @Akina а вы делаете импорт из файла, если да то как?

Comment: С MySQL/MariaDB я работаю исключительно через штатного клиента командной строки mysql.exe.